# VB.net Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview, backgroundworker

I am trying my best to figure out how to go about this error i am reciving:

***Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ListView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.***

I have a backgroundworker thats extracting cells from an excel worksheet and placing them into the listview.

Upon form load i do this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call createListView()
End Sub

Private Sub createListView()
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
    ListView1.HideSelection = False
    ListView1.MultiSelect = False

    ListView1.Columns.Add("Column Name", 150)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Column Number", 150)
End Sub
```

Then i call the backgroundworker after the user selects a file:

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        stFilePathAndName = openFileDialog1.FileName
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
        BGWxml2excel = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        BGWxml2excel.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BGWxml2excel.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        BGWxml2excel.RunWorkerAsync()
End If
```

Then i process with getting the excel column count and values so that i can populate the listview with it:

```
Private Sub BGWxml2excel_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGWxml2excel.DoWork
    Call xml2Excel(stFilePathAndName)
End Sub

Private Sub xml2Excel(ByRef theDirOfFile As String)
    Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlsWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim columnCount As Integer = 0

    xlsApp = New Excel.Application
    xlsApp.Visible = False
    xlsApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=theDirOfFile, LoadOption:=XlXmlLoadOption.xlXmlLoadImportToList)
    xlsSheet = xlsWB.Worksheets(1)
    xlsSheet.Select()
    columnCount = xlsSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    Dim x As Integer = 1

    Do Until x = columnCount + 1
        lvi.Text = xlsSheet.Cells(1, x).value
        lvi.SubItems.Add(x)

        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    'xlsSheet.SaveAs("c:\_tempExcelFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False)
    xlsWB.Close()
    xlsApp.Quit()    
End Sub
```

The error is on this line:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
```

What can i do in order to correct this odd proglem?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that only the UI thread can update the UI. Because you are adding an item to the `ListView` from your worker, you are getting this exception.

To fix this, you could store items that you want to add to the listview in a shared variable (one to which both the UI thread and your worker have access), put a timer on your form (so the UI threads hits the tick event handler) and add the items within the tick handler.

Watered-down example (in C#, because it's a lot faster for me :-) ):

```
private List<ListViewItem> _itemsToBeAdded = new List<ListViewItem>();
private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

// worker method:
private void xml2Excel(string input)
{
    // do some processing...
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    // set up lvi

    lock(_lockObject)
    {
        _itemsToBeAdded.Add(lvi);
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(_lockObject)
    {
        foreach(var item in _itemsToBeAdded)
        {
            ListView1.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the UI thread can access the UI.  Your background worker is on another thread.  You'll need to use .InvokeRequired/.Invoke to get back to the UI thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx

The event handler's for the background worker will be raised on the main thread; you can safely alter the UI there.  But actually in the background thread, you'll have to invoke.  Like this:

```
Delegate Sub SetTextCallback([text] As String)

Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)

        ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
        If Me.textBox1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
        Else
            Me.textBox1.Text = [text]
        End If
    End Sub
```